# Thesis-subjects in number theory for an undergraduate.

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for some thesis subjects with regards to number-theory. I am having a hard time looking for subjects, because i simply don't know everything of number theory. Any suggestions or tips?

Kees Til

Comment: Your advisor should give you a list of topics to choose from

Comment: By thesis do you mean it has to be something original?  Or do you just have to get a handle on some particular topic or result or something like that?

Comment: PS nobody knows everything of number theory.

Comment: @Grant Not specifically. I am just trying to gather as many topics as possible and choose the one i think that is most interesting.

So far i have this list:
1)quadratic forms

2)Diffie-Hellman / Rsa algorithms

3)Diophanic equations

4) additive number theory

5) Prime number theorem

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692543/topics-on-number-theory-for-undergraduate-to-do-a-project?rq=1).